# Отказано в доступе по пути C#

Tags: c#, io

Пишу так как в MSDN, Можно сказать копирую  с примера. Но что таким образом, что просто `File.Create` всё равно ошибка  "Отказано в доступе по пути 'c:\output.PF'". Не могу понять в чём проблема.

```
string sss = v.ToJson();
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"c:\output.PF"))
{
      Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(sss);
      // Add some information to the file.
      fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
}
```

Comment: вероятно, у вас нет прав для создания файла на диске. Попробуйте запустить программу от имени администратора, чтобы убедиться в этом.

Comment: Вообще, обращение к файлам, лучше оборачивать в try-catch

Comment: @rdorn в try-catch оберну позже. Мне же нужно что бы работало, а не просто что бы было и игнорировалось.

Comment: @rdorn, я про try-catch ни слова не сказал.

Comment: @BwehaaFox Try-Catch, нужен не для игнорирования, а для информирования, что именно произошло. Игнорировать исключения - не самая лучшая идея.

Comment: @rdorn я образно выразился. Имел ввиду что мне нужно в данной ситуации было определить проблему а не обработать её. Что произошло и так было понятно, и обработка исключений мне нового ничего не дало бы.

Comment: Зачем в корень системного диска писать? Если в любую не системную папку записывать, то скорее всего ошибки не будет и без администраторских прав.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Если студия выполняется при включенном режиме UAC от имени текущего пользователя, то запись в корневую папку системного диска недоступна.

Comment: @Попутчик, как зачем? А вдруг потребуется использовать класс для записи именно в системный раздел или в корень в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 1):

Запустил Studio от имени администратора и ошибки больше нету.

Comment: как и предполагалось, дело в правах доступа.

Comment: То есть, вам было отказано в доступе потому, что просто не было права доступа. Логично. ;-)

Comment: @VladD тут больше косяк в том, что после сброса системы не прописал Студии вновь запуск от админа:)

Comment: @BwehaaFox: Вроде бы студию не стоит запускать от админа, т. к. при этом программы могут «безнаказанно» делать вещи, которые на машине клиента будут запрещены. (Например, писать данные вне `%APPDATA%`.)